# Find the length of the smallest square?

Tags: arithmetic

A rectangular paper sheet measures 192 * 84 mm. You cut the sheet along just one
straight line to get two parts, one of which is a square. Then you do the same with the non-square part of the sheet, and so on. What is the length of the side of the smallest square you can get with this procedure?

Any Help Please Answer is 10 mm but i don't how please help.

Comment: You can get as small a square as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it step-by-step.
Substract the shorter side from the longer one, and you get a new side for a new rectangle, and the previous shorter side is the other side.
192 - 84 = 108
108 - 84 = 24
84 - 24 = 60
60 - 24 = 36
36 - 24 = 12
24 - 12 = 12
At this point you have two squares, and as I see it, the answer is 12mm.